# How to setup spell check in TortoiseHg 1.1.7?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/0.9/settings.html says I can setup spell check language. But I can't find that option in my Global Settings. Am I missing any extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.1/settings.html#module-commit.settings) also says:

> **Spell Check Language:**
>   Default language
>   for spell check. System language is
>   used if not specified. Examples: en,
>   en_GB, en_US. Spell checking requires
>   gtkspell, which is only available on
>   Gnome PCs.

Are you using Gnome?  Have you installed "gtkspell"?